# How to change HTML on clients when DB changes on server in Django

Tags: html, django, sqlite, sockets

I am working on a project in which Django is running on a Beaglebone board. The Beaglebone is connected to a wireless router via a wifi-stick. Multiple devices (computers, smartphones) connect to the wireless router to access the Django app. The app uses a SQLite DB to store some information. Whenever a device accesses the Django app, an HTML page (which contains information from DB) is rendered. A device can perform an action that will update/change a table's content in the DB.

**My question is**: Is it possible to update the rendered HTML page on ALL currently connected devices if ANY connected device causes a change in the DB stored on the Beaglebone board without manually refreshing the HTML page? I am restricted to not use another port/socket so I don't think an event listener is an option. Somebody suggested to put a timer/timeout in the HTML rendered pages (using JS) that will continuously keep sending a request to the server (using GET/POST) and the server will send back changed data. However, I do not think this is a good idea. Imagine 5, 6 devices connected to the server continuously sending requests. In my opinion, this could cause congestion on the wireless network.

Any ideas on how this issue can be resolved would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try JQuery. You can continuously update the client's view when you detect a change in the database that will affect your clients. Only then will you send a response to the client which will change the data in the view, but not the whole page. This will prevent clients from having to reload their page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Bob. Will the client have to request the server to respond with any changes made at the server-side? If so, isn't it the same as continuously pinging the server?

Comment: Or is there a way in which the server can inform the client whenever a change is made at the server-side? This would eliminate the need for the client to send requests.

Comment: Yes, so you can just send responses from the server when the server sees that the database change is relevant. Then, as sockets always need to be listening for changes, it will hear it. As far as AJAX with JQuery works, I don't think it continuously pings the server. If you're curious about this, I suggest you look into how notifications work. I think the idea was that the process sleeps until another process wakes it up and tells it that its ready for the sleeping process to do some work.